# Books for learning c# & .NET

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Can any experienced developers recommend any DECENT resources written specifically for visual studio 2010. A lot of the resources online seem to be out of date...

I'm particularly interested in any books people have used and can recommend

Answer (score 2):

[Jon Skeet's C# In Depth, Second Edition](http://www.manning.com/skeet2/)

It only covers advanced topics (it assumes knowledge of the basics). Focus is on features added in recent versions of .Net (up to 4.0) - including generics, iterator blocks, LINQ, parallels and Dynamic Language Runtime.

Very educative and fun book.

Answer (score 2):

[CLR via C#](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_4/185-0455864-3243625?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=clr%20via%20c&x=0&y=0&sprefix=clr%20#/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=clr%20via%20c#&rh=i%3aaps,k%3aclr%20via%20c#)

Answer (score 1):

- [C# Essentials](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/C_Sharp_Essentials)
- [C# Programming - Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Sharp_Programming)
- [C# Yellow Book](http://www.csharpcourse.com/) (intro to programming)
- [Charles Petzold's .NET Book Zero](http://www.charlespetzold.com/dotnet/index.html)
- [Data Structures and Algorithms with Object-Oriented Design Patterns in C#](http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus6/)
- [Entity Framework](http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/12/05/my-christmas-present-to-the-entity-framework-community.aspx)
- [Illustrated C# 2008](http://downloads.red-gate.com/ebooks/DotNet/illustratedcsharp2008.zip) (.zip, dead link)
- [Nemerle](http://asaha.com/ebook/AMTQ2NjA-/Nemerle.pdf#)
- [O'Reilly's C# Pocket Reference Manual](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/be_ahead_of_the_game_ebook.htm?utm_source=simpletalk&utm_medium=email&utm_content=nlv_aheadofgame-ebook&utm_campaign=antsperformanceprofiler) (dead link)
- [Programmer's Heaven C# School Book](http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/CSharpBook) (covers C# 1.0 and 2.0)
- [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)
- [Visual Basic Essentials](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Visual_Basic_Essentials)
- [Visual Studio Tips and Tricks](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/vsnettt) (VS 2003-2005 only)

Comment: Is it a copy and paste answer? Are you expecting the question author to start with all of them in one go? how Visual Basic Essentials is relevant to the question?

Answer (score 1):

[Deitel and Deitel: Visual C# 2010 How to Program](http://www.deitel.com/Books/C/VisualC2010HowtoProgram/tabid/3607/Default.aspx) (good enough for beginners in C#)

[More Effective C#: 50 Specific Ways to Improve Your C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321485890) (Comprehensive book for tips and tricks, although for framework 3.0...)

It still depends on what you are actually looking for. C# used with ASP.NET and other web technologies, is covered in the Deitel and Deitel book.

Moreover,  @Gaurav Agrawal provided a very good list for you.

Answer (score 0):

The only book with keeping both aspects on index well defined is [Pro C# 2010 and .NET 4.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430225491) from Andrew troelson...Very nice book and i am reading it now.

The other book i would recommend is [Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Step by Step](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780735626706.do). Its a very good book with example practices for every chapter. You might love this one too.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your level of experience the 'Sams Teach Yourself in 21 Days' is a fantastic range covering almost every language and tech. I used the Teach Yourself C# in 21 Days when I was first learning and it was invaluable and still useful today as a reference. Easy to understand and comes with a CD full of examples. It moves from the very basics to some of the more advanced topics towards the end and builds up your skills from the ground up. I would highly recommend that.

Answer (score 0):

Eric Lippert's recommended reading list:

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1769249